# Can a lambda function return a defined function in Python?

Tags: python, lambda

I want to return a comparison function from a lambda function and use it depending on the type of the input. Is there a way to do it?

```
def p12(p):
    f = lambda p: compare_nr if type(p) == int else compare_str
    return f
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmp1 = p12(0)
    cmp1(2,3)
    cmp2 = p12('')
    cmp2('Mississippi','fall')
```

Comment: Yeah sure, what isn't working? As an aside a `lambda` shouldn't be used if you are going to name it anyway... it defeats the entire *purpose* of an **anonymous function**.

Comment: cmp1(2, 3)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: yeah just remove `lambda`.

Comment: The thing is that I am not allowed to remove [tag:lambda]

Comment: What do you mean you aren't allowed???

Comment: It's for a code challenge

Comment: What exactly are your requirements. Please be specific. This coding challange *enforces the use of lambda?* That sounds silly.

Comment: Asking someone to complete the challenge for you defeats the entire purpose.

Comment: I know, I'm a novice in python and it bugged me for hours

Comment: If you're a novice, your first resource should be books and tutorials, not posting a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem encountered was that I returned the actual **lambda** function instead of the **defined** one.

```
def p12(p):
    f = lambda p: compare_nr if type(p) == int else compare_str

    #here was the problem
    #return f
    return f(p)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmp1 = p12(0)
    cmp1(2,3)
    cmp2 = p12('')
    cmp2('Mississippi','fall')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it (in Python 3) without using a `lambda`: [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch). With this, you can create a [single-dispatch generic function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch):

> A form of generic function dispatch where the implementation is chosen
>   based on the **type** of a single argument.

[*Emphasis mine*]

It adds overloaded implementations to the function which are called depending on the **`type`** of the first argument, and fortunately, your `p12` function takes only one argument.

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def p12(p):
     ...

@p12.register(int)
def _(p):
     '''compare integers'''
     ...

@p12.register(str)
def _(p):
     '''compare strings'''
     ...
```

---

```
p12(0) # calls integer dispatch
p12('') # calls string dispatch
```

And you can still add more candidate functions for other Python types to overload `p12`.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively replace lambda with a higher order function and do the same.

```
def p12(p):
    if type(p) == int :
        return compare_nr
    else:
        return compare_str

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmp1 = p12(0)
    cmp1(2,3)
    cmp2 = p12('')
    cmp2('Mississippi','fall')
```